# how to remove horizontal scroll bar in mobile view?

Tags: html, css

In bootstrap3 I am trying to remove horizontal scroll bar in mobile it looks fine in desktop view but in mobile view the horizontal bar is shown I read that horizontal bar comes due to **container-fluid** so to I used  tag but it is not work

here is the code

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">RG ACADEMY</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">About us <span class="caret"> </span> </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#about">About Academy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Faculty Team</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Courses <span class="caret"> </span> </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">JEE MAINS+ADVANCED</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">JEE MAINS</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>


            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Results <span class="caret"> </span> </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">IIT JEE 2015</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">JEE MAINS 2015</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

           <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Exams Info <span class="caret"> </span> </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
                <li><a href="#">JEE MAINS + ADVANCED</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BITSAT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">KVPY</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>

           <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Downloads<span class="caret"> </span> </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
                <li><a href="#">IIT JEE Solutions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">JEE MAINS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">KVPY</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Enquiry</a></li>
            </ul>

           <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyhicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
           </ul>  

        </div>
    </div>

  </nav>
```

Comment: Did you add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` to your template header?

Comment: Your html has no horizontal scroll bar see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c259LrpL/2/

Comment: yes I already added in html file

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

in css or declarate it deirect in the html:

```
<style type="text/css">
.container-fluid {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Please make you CSS valid

Comment: It's `.container-fluid`

Comment: Thank's! Sry I forgot it ;)

Comment: Try this! Try one or all

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine to me. You probably have some custom CSS doing something wrong. I even tried excluding "viewport" meta tag, still doesn't show overflow.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">RG ACADEMY</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">About us <span class="caret"> </span> </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#about">About Academy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Faculty Team</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Courses <span class="caret"> </span> </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">JEE MAINS+ADVANCED</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">JEE MAINS</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>


                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Results <span class="caret"> </span> </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">IIT JEE 2015</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">JEE MAINS 2015</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Exams Info <span class="caret"> </span> </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">JEE MAINS + ADVANCED</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">BITSAT</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">KVPY</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Downloads<span class="caret"> </span> </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">IIT JEE Solutions</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">JEE MAINS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">KVPY</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="#">Enquiry</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyhicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I mentioned in problem overflow problem comes when I see in mobile view to check the design is responsive may or may not. Then the overflow problem is come